# ExtJS - Embed html pages inside tabs

Tags: javascript, extjs

I'm using this group tabs example from ExtJS:
http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/examples/grouptabs/grouptabs.html

What do I need to do so when I click a link on one of the left tabs to embed an existing html page inside the main body on the right?Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way would be to get the [ManagedIFrame](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?71961-3.0.x-3.1.1-ux.ManagedIFrame-2.x) extension.

With this extension, in your group's items config, include this -

```
{
    xtype : 'iframepanel',
    id : "mif-panel",
    defaultSrc : 'http://yahoo.com'
}
```